# Node-RED not able to access to array member

Tags: json, node-red

I'm trying to access to a JSON array returned by a OpenWeatherMap request.
The JSON data is:

```
{ "city":  
  { "id": 3171457, "name": "New York", "coord": { "lon": 0.32898, "lat": 4.802662 }, "country": "US", "population": 0, "sys": { "population": 0 } }, 
  "cod": "200", "message": 0.0317, "cnt": 40, 
  "list": [ { "dt": 1483552800, "main": { "temp": 277.28, "temp_min": 275.705, "temp_max": 277.28, "pressure": 1013.85, "sea_level": 1021.42, "grnd_level": 1013.85, "humidity": 93, "temp_kf": 1.57 }, "weather": [ { "id": 800, "main": "Clear", "description": "clear sky", "icon": "01n" } ], "clouds": { "all": 0 }, "wind": { "speed": 4.74, "deg": 269.002 }, "sys": { "pod": "n" }, "dt_txt": "2017-01-04 18:00:00" },  
...
```

If i use in a template {{payload.list}} I see a list of [object Object]s.
But if I use {{payload.list[0]}}, or {{payload.list[0].main}}, I see nothing - my guess was a single [object Object].
How can i access to the first member and inner members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template node uses the `mustache` format, documented here: https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

To access array values, you should use the following syntax:

```
{{ payload.list.0 }}
```

and

```
{{ payload.list.0.main }}
```